# ASP.NET Core WebApi HttpResponseMessage create custom message?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

How can I create custom message in ASP.NET Core WebApi ?
For example I want to return

```
new HttpResponseMessage()
{
    StatusCode=HttpStatusCode.OK,
    Message="Congratulations !!"
};

new HttpResponseMessage()
{ 
    StatusCode=HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
    Message="Sorry !!"
};
```

Comment: Related post - [Convert from HttpResponseMessage to IActionResult in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51641641/465053)

Answer (score 21):

This simplest method is to use the helpers from the base Controller class.

```
public ActionResult ExampleNotFound()
{
    return NotFound("Sorry !!");            
}

public ActionResult ExampleOk()
{
    return Ok("Congratulations !!");
}
```

Alternatively you can return a new `ContentResult` and set it's status code.

```
return new ContentResult
     {
         Content = "Congratulations !!",
         ContentType = "text/plain",
         StatusCode = 200
     };
```

These two methods are slightly different, the `ContentResult` will always have a `ContentType` of `text/plain`

The `Ok()` and `NotFound()` methods return an `ObjectResult` which uses a formatter to serialize your string according to the content types in the Accept header from the request.

Comment: Hi believe his asking for HttpResponseMessage which is very different from ActionResult, ActionResult is for MVC apps while the other is for Web API.

Comment: @jersoft MVC and WebAPI are merged in ASP.Net core.

Answer (score 5):

In order to return legacy `HttpResponseMessage`, you need to convert it to `ResponseMessageResult` in .net core. The following is an example.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Guid id)
    {
        var responseMessage = HttpContext.GetHttpRequestMessage().CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
            new YourObject()
            {
                Id = Id,
                Name = Name
            });

        return new ResponseMessageResult(responseMessage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `CreateResponse` you can use the `StatusCode`.
The `StatusCode` is in the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`.

```
public virtual ObjectResult StatusCode([ActionResultStatusCode] int statusCode, [ActionResultObjectValue] object value);
```

Below is syntax.

```
return StatusCode(Convert.ToInt32(returnstatus.StatusCode), senderResponse);
```

Return type of the method will be `IActionResult`