# How to return Unathorized from .Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I do have simple API controller, and I do need to return 401.
Method's return type is not `IActionResult` so I can't just `return Unauthorized()`

How can I return Unauthorized in this case?

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public class MyController : Comntroller
{
    public SomeData GetSomeData([FromBody]RequestData data)
    {
        if(!CheckAccessCondition(data, GetCurrentUser()))
            // ?? how to return from here 401
        ///
    }
}
```

**Update**:

1. Using `IActionResult` is not a way. It is not type safe from one side, and would not allow to generate C# & Typescript clients for my API (now i'm using NSwag for this purpose)
2. It would be great to avoid throwing exception because of performance (throwing exception is really expensive operation)
3. Some update about checking access condition - I do need to check if authorized user has right to manipulate with request data. So for using some "authorization-like" attribute it would be great to do the check after request data was deserialized (to avoid double deserialization, once again - because of performance)

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992033/asp-net-core-webapi-httpresponsemessage-create-custom-message)

Comment: create an action filter to check your access condition and apply it globally.  return the 401 from that and not the controller action.

Comment: why isn't the return type IActionResult?

Comment: and do you still want to return json if it is unauthorized?

Comment: in the latest version you can now do `ActionResult<SomeData>`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If the only reason you don't have a IActionResult return type is because you want to return json data, you can still return it and do this:

```
public IActionResult GetSomeData()
{
    if (condition) 
      return Json(myData);
    else 
      return Unauthorized();
}
```

A little hacky, but you can also simply return null and configure your response using `HttpContext`

```
public SomeData GetSomeData()
{
    if (condition) return myData;
    else 
    {
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return null;
    }

}
```

If you need `SomeData` for some reason such as type safety, one of your options are to set up a filter class.

```
public class MyAccessAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter{

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (condition)
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

You can then use it on your action like this:

```
[MyAccess]
public SomeData GetSomeData(){
```

**Update**
As of .netcore 2.1 you can now use generic ActionResult

```
 public ActionResult<SomeData> GetSomeData(){
```

Comment: I do return concrete data type because it is type safe, from one side, and I can easily generate clients for my API (c# & typescript) with NSwag, for example. So I don't want to use `IActionResult`. Using `MyAccess` is the way, but not easy one, because I do need check for current user & method data...

Comment: you can still check for current user and method data and basically anything you can check inside the controller. but is this ONLY when the user is logged in and is the check ALWAYS related to the user data? because in that case there is another method to be followed

Answer (score 6):

You may return something like this:

```
return StatusCode(statusCode);
```

or

```
return Unauthorized();
```

Since `StatusCode()` and `Unauthorized()` return an ActionResult, you'll want to change your action's return type to `IActionResult` instead. (Which means while you'll need to return your actual value as `Ok(yourValue)`).

**Example:**

```
public IActionResult GetSomeData()
{
    if(!CheckAccessCondition())
        return Unauthorized();
    return Ok(somevalue);
}
```

ASP.NET core introduced authorization policies. Read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies).

Comment: that's a link to WCF documentation?

Comment: @KeithNicholas oops. Corrected the link. Thanks!

Comment: What if you need to return `ObjectResult` ?

Answer (score 1):

Logically you have first to change the return type of you method. Then you can handle it as below:

```
public IActionResult GetSomeData()
{
    if(!CheckAccessCondition()) return HttpUnauthorized();
}
```